# SimGrid. Model abnormal situations

Tags: java, simgrid

What is the SimGrid way of modeling abnormal situations with network of hosts? For example, how to model break of link routes? `Master` creates some `task` and `dsend`s it to worker. But in case of broken link, this task will be lost. But `master` doesn't know about broken links and may continue to `dsend` new `task` to `worker`.

**UPDATED**

I added .fail file to `state_file` attribute of platform.xml.

```
PERIODICITY 10.0
1.0 1
2.0 0
```

Error occurs, when `worker` stops working.
 What is the way to handle it?

```
** SimGrid: UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION received on java(2): category: action canceled; value: 0
** �;
** Thrown by LHCb.Tier1() in this process
[Tier1_1:LHCb.Tier1:(2) 2.000000] /builds/workspace/SimGrid-Multi/build_mode/Debug/node/simgrid-ubuntu-trusty-64/build/SimGrid-3.13/src/xbt/ex.c:140: [xbt_ex/CRITICAL] �;

**   In _ZN7simgrid4java11JavaContext4stopEv() at /builds/workspace/SimGrid-Multi/build_mode/Debug/node/simgrid-ubuntu-trusty-64/build/SimGrid-3.13/src/bindings/java/JavaContext.cpp:144
**   In SIMIX_process_yield() at /builds/workspace/SimGrid-Multi/build_mode/Debug/node/simgrid-ubuntu-trusty-64/build/SimGrid-3.13/src/simix/smx_process.cpp:1014
**   In simcall_execution_wait() at /builds/workspace/SimGrid-Multi/build_mode/Debug/node/simgrid-ubuntu-trusty-64/build/SimGrid-3.13/src/simix/libsmx.cpp:276
**   In MSG_parallel_task_execute() at /builds/workspace/SimGrid-Multi/build_mode/Debug/node/simgrid-ubuntu-trusty-64/build/SimGrid-3.13/src/msg/msg_gos.cpp:90
**   In MSG_host_del_task() at /builds/workspace/SimGrid-Multi/build_mode/Debug/node/simgrid-ubuntu-trusty-64/build/SimGrid-3.13/src/msg/msg_vm.cpp:521
**   In ExceptionOccurred() at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h:825
**   In ?? at [0x7f7aa8e09d98]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you need for that exists in SimGrid, under the name of *failures*, but unfortunately a bit sparsely documented. You want to add a state trace file to your hosts or links.

Please refer to [the documentation](http://simgrid.gforge.inria.fr/simgrid/3.13/doc/platform.html#pf_host_churn) or the [platform tutorial](http://simgrid.gforge.inria.fr/tutorials/simgrid-platf-101.pdf#19). You can find an example of use in the archive, in the file examples/platforms/faulty_host.xml.

Note that it describes the failures of hosts, but that's exactly the same for the failures of links, which can be given a state file too in the XML.

Answer (score 2):

The message doesn't say that an error occurred but that an exception has been raised without being caught (UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION). Then the answer to the question "What is the way to handle it?" is to add a try/catch block. What to do in the catch block is up to you (resend, abort, display a message, ...) as it is part of your simulated application, not the responsibility of the simulation toolkit.

Comment: The problem is that this is a C exception, that kills the java simulation because of an internal bug in the bindings.